# Error on import pandas python - DLL cannot be found

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot compile script with pandas library. My code is simple `import pandas as pd`. I get error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\Desktop\Python\var dzēst\k.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import DataFrameGroupBy, NamedAgg, SeriesGroupBy
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py", line 60, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 124, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4572, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 10349, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core.window import EWM, Expanding, Rolling, Window
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.window.ewm import EWM  # noqa:F401
  File "C:\Users\Valters_Kalme\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window\ewm.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing aggregations: The specified module could not be found.
```

I believe key word is `DLL load failed`.
I cannot install pandas on this Windows PC with Anaconda as this is enterprise PC and Anaconda is free only for individual use. So I installed pandas with `pip install pandas`. When I run it again it gives back message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in c:\users\valters_kalme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (1.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.6.1 in c:\users\valters_kalme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\valters_kalme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (1.18.5)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.2 in c:\users\valters_kalme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from pandas) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\valters_kalme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.6.1->pandas) (1.15.0)
```

What possible could be wrong? Thank you!

Comment: can you import `numpy`  like that or does it also fail?

Comment: I can, this script `import numpy as ny` works well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try uninstalling pandas and installing it again:

```
pip uninstall pandas
pip install pandas==1.0.1
```

changing the version of pandas according to you python version could help, you could also try to uninstall or update pandas and numpy.

Comment: Yes, it worked! In addition to that I was asked to install `openpyxl`, which I did like `pip install openpyxl`. And now all works! Thank you!